# Go Composed Interface Instance

Tags: go, interface, embedding

For a composite interface e.g.

```
type io.ReadWriter interface {
    io.Reader
    io.Writer
}
```

Is it possible to wrap the implementation instance on the fly from separate partial implementations without defining intermediate proxy structures types

```
func() io.ReadWriter {
    var reader io.Reader
    var writer io.Writer

    return ...
}
```

e.g. something like `io.ReadWriter{reader, writer}`.
Or is the most shorthand inline approach would be only like this?

```
return struct{
    io.Reader
    io.Writer
}{
    reader, 
    writer
}
```

Comment: your last snippet would work ; there is no inline declaration that would look like your first attempt.